# Android rating bar custom image for each star

Tags: android, xml, android-styles, ratingbar

Hello people i was wondering is it possible to set custom image for each star in rating bar like the following:
1 star for crying face
2 star for sad face
3 star for meh face
4 star for smiling face
5 star for happy face.

Just wondering how can i achieve this using custom rating bar styles.

Comment: you have to create your own custom bar for this

Comment: can you tell me how i searched through but they just use 2 images one fro empty star and one for filled star but i am using 5 custom images

Comment: that again uses 2 images

Answer (score 0):

Bingo!!
Have a look at this library [starBar by badoo](https://github.com/badoo/StarBar.git)  having one to ten stars with different color images like red orange yellow green u can change the images in resource to get your choice of bar. 
I only found this solution after searching a lot hope it may work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.